# How can i stop database retry connection? using c3po

Tags: java, spring, c3p0

How can i stop database retry connection?using c3po i.e in my application i want to stop retry connection when i get database communication is fail

Answer (score 8):

[C3P0 documentation](http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/)

1. Set up c3p0.properties in root of classpath
2. acquireRetryAttempts=1

Answer (score 3):

As MJB says, setting c3p0's config parameter acquireRetryAttempts to 1 will cause clients to merely experience an Exception on a Connection acquisition failure rather than waiting and retrying.

If you wish for a c3p0 Connection pool to nevermore attempt to Connect to the database after a round of acquisition failures (with a "round" being defined by acquireRetryAttempts), set the config parameter breakAfterAcquireFailure to true. (By default this is false, c3p0 will try again to acquire Connections when new clients come calling.)

http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/#acquireRetryAttempts

http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/#breakAfterAcquireFailure